# Timing on malloc and free

Tags: c, allocation

I'm trying to understand the timings of `malloc` and `free`. 
So I wrote this simple program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int
main()
{
  long i;
  for(i = 2; i < 10000000000; i*=2) {
    struct timeval start, end;
    double timing ;
    long j;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    double *vect = malloc((size_t) i * sizeof(*vect));
    if (!vect) {
      printf("malloc failed\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    timing =  (double) (end.tv_sec * 1e6 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1e6 + start.tv_usec);
    printf("size %ld allocating (%f)\t", i * sizeof(*vect), timing);
    /* I do this to avoid lazy allocation */
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
      vect[i] = 2;

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
    free(vect);
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    timing =  (double) (end.tv_sec * 1e6 + end.tv_usec) - (start.tv_sec * 1e6 + start.tv_usec);
    printf("deallocating (%f)\n", timing);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program looks
This is what I get as ouput:

```
size 16 allocating (40.000000)  deallocating (0.000000)
size 32 allocating (0.000000)   deallocating (0.000000)
size 64 allocating (0.000000)   deallocating (0.000000)
size 128 allocating (0.000000)  deallocating (1.000000)
size 256 allocating (0.000000)  deallocating (0.000000)
size 512 allocating (0.000000)  deallocating (0.000000)
size 1024 allocating (1.000000) deallocating (0.000000)
size 2048 allocating (0.000000) deallocating (0.000000)
size 4096 allocating (1.000000) deallocating (0.000000)
size 8192 allocating (1.000000) deallocating (0.000000)
size 16384 allocating (1.000000)    deallocating (0.000000)
size 32768 allocating (1.000000)    deallocating (1.000000)
size 65536 allocating (1.000000)    deallocating (0.000000)
size 131072 allocating (1.000000)   deallocating (1.000000)
size 262144 allocating (2.000000)   deallocating (4.000000)
size 524288 allocating (2.000000)   deallocating (2.000000)
size 1048576 allocating (1.000000)  deallocating (2.000000)
size 2097152 allocating (3.000000)  deallocating (3.000000)
size 4194304 allocating (2.000000)  deallocating (4.000000)
size 8388608 allocating (4.000000)  deallocating (3.000000)
size 16777216 allocating (2.000000) deallocating (3.000000)
size 33554432 allocating (3.000000) deallocating (2.000000)
size 67108864 allocating (2.000000) deallocating (7.000000)
size 134217728 allocating (7.000000)    deallocating (8.000000)
size 268435456 allocating (6.000000)    deallocating (8.000000)
size 536870912 allocating (5.000000)    deallocating (10.000000)
size 1073741824 allocating (6.000000)   deallocating (12.000000)
size 2147483648 allocating (25.000000)  deallocating (13.000000)
size 4294967296 allocating (7.000000)   deallocating (11.000000)
size 8589934592 allocating (6.000000)   deallocating (11.000000)
```

I'm really surprised how cheap the `malloc` is when the size of the vector is increasing. Shouldn't it be increasing more drastically with the size?

And my second question is about the `free` function. I always thought the `malloc` is the expensive one, and not `free`. It is more expensive, which for me does not make sense.

I have some knowledge on how the system handles the memory (physical pages and virtual pages), but these results done make sense to me. `malloc` is not that expensive  after all... or is it? :)

Any comments are welcomed!

edit: 
Thank a lot for all the fast comments! Very appreciated!  I took into account the comments and I changed a bit my program. Instead of using malloc I used calloc. Additionally I go two time through the array and I time both of them. One in order to make sure that all the pages are allocated and the second one to test the timing of just accessing the array. There is clearly a difference that increases with the size of the array!

I'm trying to get  some performance result of my algorithm, so I would like to get rid of this additional cost. Most of the memory used in my algo is allocated in the beginning. **Is there any way to tell malloc to allocate and associate the memory?** The goal it to have more reproducible (and better :) ) results.

```
size 262144 allocating (5.000000)   first pass (166.000000) second pass (190.000000)    diff between passes (24.000000) deallocating (10.000000)
size 524288 allocating (4.000000)   first pass (330.000000) second pass (328.000000)    diff between passes (2.000000)  deallocating (3.000000)
size 1048576 allocating (2.000000)  first pass (669.000000) second pass (673.000000)    diff between passes (4.000000)  deallocating (5.000000)
size 2097152 allocating (5.000000)  first pass (1326.000000)    second pass (1314.000000)   diff between passes (12.000000) deallocating (6.000000)
size 4194304 allocating (4.000000)  first pass (2655.000000)    second pass (2586.000000)   diff between passes (69.000000) deallocating (5.000000)
size 8388608 allocating (4.000000)  first pass (4858.000000)    second pass (4838.000000)   diff between passes (20.000000) deallocating (5.000000)
size 16777216 allocating (3.000000) first pass (9034.000000)    second pass (8458.000000)   diff between passes (576.000000)    deallocating (4.000000)
size 33554432 allocating (3.000000) first pass (15702.000000)   second pass (14375.000000)  diff between passes (1327.000000)   deallocating (4.000000)
size 67108864 allocating (4.000000) first pass (25785.000000)   second pass (23228.000000)  diff between passes (2557.000000)   deallocating (3.000000)
```

Comment: It's totally implementation dépendent.

Comment: In many implementations, a call to malloc doesn't do anything except modifying some bytes of metadata, regardless of the malloc'd size. Perhaps `calloc()` meets your expectations better, since it initializes the memory.

Comment: Timing only *one* call to malloc or free is not accurate. Too many external things can influence it. You should at least time many of them before you get significant figures. And even then, the order in which these allocations take place can also influence the timing. And, as others say, it is implementation dependent. There are many different allocation algorithms, and some are faster than others in some things, and others are faster in other things, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most cases, this is **very** implementation dependent. But let us try to see how a typical malloc implementation would work.

In your case when the allocation size is small, the allocator tries to avoid internal fragmentation and does very compact allocations. This means some pages are already allocated and then future allocations are done from the same pages. This is a little bit clear by how your first allocation takes a bit more time than others(it also does heap data structure initialization here).

Anyway, each of these operations (of allocating small chunks) are equal in cost since it is just a few pointer updates. The allocation through `sbrk` or `mmap` is already done (Until it needs to allocate more).

Now coming to the bigger allocations. In these cases, many allocators simply fall back to mapping new pages(after page aligning the size). This requires new pages being allocated which is a system call.

Page allocation levels are done at page granularity. Which means that the updates needed to be done will be order of number of pages (again this is very operating system dependent, on some systems allocating one page might be equally costly as allocating 10000 pages).

As mentioned by @Ctx, most modern operating systems do not even update the page tables at the time of `sbrk` or `mmap` but they do it when the data is actually read/written on the pages. So the commit might be just some internal data structures being updated in the kernel.

Coming to free, it is generally very cheap for small allocations since it only involves returning the allocation to the free list and 1 or 2 merges. The heap doesn't necessarily return the pages in this case.

For big allocations the story is similar to allocation. A system call is made to de-commit the pages. The operation may or may not be proportional to number of pages.

Another factor which might affect your timings is the default behavior of your allocator. `malloc` is not required to clear the memory before returning it, but some allocators do that (basically they behave like `calloc`). In that case the cost of malloc may go up linearly. It might be worth while in your case to also do a similar comparison for `calloc` with different sizes.

Comment: The page allocation with recent OS is done when the page is written to (in the pagefault handler), and not on calls to `mmap()/sbrk()` at malloc()-time.

Comment: @Ctx I agree. Even though all the new pages are committed, they might be added to the page tables only at the time of first access. I will add this point to the answer.